# excel vlookup inside countif criteria

Tags: excel, criteria, vlookup, countif

I am trying to combine a countif in excel with the criteria retrieved from a vlookup table. This sounds simple enough, but I am having trouble making it work.

=countif(a1:z1,">=4")
I want the column values from a to z counted every time the value is greater than or equal to 4 which is my criteria.

But I don't want to type the four in the above formula.
I want it to come from a vlookup.

VLOOKUP("myValue",AA1:DD4,2,FALSE)   <--formula would retrieve the 4

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: What if VLOOKUP fails? Should it all fail, return zero or countif a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `">=4"` a parameter, you just need to do some string building:

```
">=" & VLOOKUP("myValue",AA1:DD4,2,FALSE)
```

The full formula would be:

```
=COUNTIF(a1:z1,">=" & VLOOKUP("myValue",AA1:DD4,2,FALSE))
```

The `&` operator is a shorthand for `=CONCATENATE(,)` which is a long word for "join strings together".